# Entropy of $n$ particles in a $N \times N$ grid with neighbouring forbidden sites

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

Imagine an $N \times N$-grid on which $n$ particles should be distributed. In a non-interacting case (while each grid point can accommodate max 1 particle), the entropy is given by:

$$S = k_{\mathrm B}\ln\frac{N_{\mathrm{tot}}!}{(N_{\mathrm{tot}}-n)!n!}$$

with $N_{\mathrm{tot}} = N\times N$.

Now imagine that each particle not only occupies one grid point, but no 2 particles are allowed to sit next to each other. In other words each particle occupies the neighbouring 4 sites (up, down, left & right). I hope the diagram below helps you understand the problem.

Now the question: What's the entropy?

I first thought that the entropy simply grows 5 times as fast and therefore replaced $n$ by $5n$, but then realised that two particles can share forbidden sites (as the figure below shows), so I presume that it grows with $5n$ only when $n$ is small, but then $n$ can go up to $N_{\mathrm{tot}}/2$ before the entropy becomes zero.

[image: Explanation for what's allowed and what's not]

Comment: What is the relation between $n$ and $N$? If you let $N,n\to\infty$ in such a way that $n/N \to \rho > 0$, so that you have a positive limited density of particles, then I don't think that an explicit answer is known, although reasonable bounds are available.

Comment: There's no particular relationship between $n$ and $N$ I would set beforehand. Frankly any help would be appreciated because for other than $n \approx 0$ and $n \approx N_{\mathrm{tot}}/2$, I really don't know what it looks like.